# How to remove malfunctioning desktop manager from Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, boot, lightdm

I have accidentally installed LightDM as my desktop manager on my Arch Linux virtual machine and now the virtual machine won't boot; it just gives the following output:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start light display manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target graphical interface.
_
```

Then the vm just halts, the cursor still blinks but I cannot type and it does nothing.

Comment: Change [the default target](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Change_default_target_to_boot_into).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change anything, insert the live medium which you used to install Arch Linux, mount your drives, run arch-chroot, and then remove lightdm. Maybe it won't start because you did not install and configure the necessary greeter, so you might do this instead.